# Animation in swiftui how to decrease slowly the duration in each repeat

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom ImageView and i use a scaleEffect to animate / scale the ImageView using the code below

```
ImageView(named: imagename)
    .padding(.trailing, 16)
    .padding(.top, 105)
    .scaleEffect(scale)
    .onAppear {
        let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)
        let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatCount(5, autoreverses: true)

        withAnimation(repeated) {
            scale = 0.5
        }
    }
```

Tha imageview scales to 0.5 five times. Each one repeat completes in 0.5 seconds. I need the following. I have to change the duration of the easeInOut by 0.1 for each repeat. So first time the animation is going to complete in 0.5 seconds. Second time it repeats should complete in 0.4 seconds and so on. Is this possible using withAnimation? Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: GeometryEffect would be helpful

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for your suggestion sir I will take a look into GeometryEffect